# Subset Sum Problem: Returning a Variant of the Required Subset

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, subset-sum

**Problem description:**

Given a list of integers and a target sum, we're required to return another list containing Booleans. This Boolean list represents the subset that we're looking for.

**Example:**

Input: list (3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2), target = 9.

Output: (false, false, true, false, true, false) (since 4+5 = 9; notice that this solution is not unique, but the problem only asks for one arbitrary solution).

**My attempt:**

I started with writing a method that checks if a solution even exists:

```
boolean subsetSumRec(List<Integer> list, int i, int sum) { //i is the index of the last element in list
    if(sum==0){
        return true;
    } else if(i<0 || sum<0){
        return false;
    }
    boolean include = subsetSumRec(list,i-1,sum-list.get(n));
    boolean exclude = subsetSumRec(list,i-1,sum);
    return include || exclude;
}
```

I made a new ArrayList (type: Boolean) *resultList*, that will be the output. My plan was to update *resultList* within the method subsetSumRec. It would be something like:

```
private boolean subsetSumRec(List<Integer> list, int i, int sum) {
    if(sum==0){
        return true;
    } else if(list.size()<=0 || sum<0){
        return false;
    }
    res.add(true);
    boolean include = subsetSumRec(list,i-1,sum-list.get(i));
    boolean exclude;
    if(include == false){
        res.remove(true);
        res.add(false);
        exclude = subsetSumRec(list, i - 1, sum);
    }
    return include || exclude;
}
```

This does not give the required result, but I don't see what's going wrong. How can this be optimized?

If updating *resultList* within subsetSumRec is not an option, then I'd have to get rid of the method that checks if there is a solution and use a backtracking algorithm (no dynamic programming!). I don't know how to start with the last one. Could somebody give me hint as to how to approach a backtracking algorithm for this problem (pseudocode?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"This does not give the required result, but I don't see what's going wrong. How can this be optimized?"* Firstly, you need to edit the question to say specifically what is wrong about the result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Secondly, optimising an algorithm that gives wrong answers only means you will get wrong answers faster.

Comment: What does this, `if(include = false)`, mean? Did you mean, `if(include == false)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example recursion in JavaScript. We return the second list if the solution is feasible, otherwise `false`.

```js
function f(A, S, B=new Array(A.length).fill(false), i=A.length - 1){
  if (A[i] == S){
    B[i] = true
    return B
  }
    
  if (i == 0){
    if (A[i] == S){
      B[i] = true
      return B
    }
    return false
  }
  
  if (A[i] <= S){
    let maybeB = f(A, S - A[i], B, i - 1)
    if (maybeB){
      B[i] = true
      return B
    }
  }

  return f(A, S, B, i - 1)
}

var A = [3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2]
var S = 9

console.log(JSON.stringify(A))
console.log(`Target: ${S}`)
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, S)))

S = 199
console.log(`\nTarget: ${S}`)
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, S)))
```